# Wix 4 set folder permission

Tags: c#, .net, wix, wix4

I am trying to set ACL permissions of the folder where my application gets installed via Wix 4. I want all the users to be able to read/write it, even if they don't have Admin access.

Following is my code

```
<Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)">
        <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

but when i build it, i get

`error WIX0005: The Directory element contains an unexpected child element 'PermissionEx'.`

Answer (score 0):

Permissions change machine state, and all changes to machine state by the Windows Installer must be contained in a Component. Something like:

```
<Directory Id="CompanyFolder" Name="!(bind.Property.Manufacturer)">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="!(bind.Property.ProductName)">
    <Component>
      <util:PermissionEx User="Users" GenericAll="yes" />
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

In [episode 28 of the Deployment Dojo show](https://youtube.com/live/DslwxSg5fPw) I show how to add permissions and refine it in [episode 29](https://youtube.com/live/-QKbP4uDy9w)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the Youtube series, i'll surely take a look at it in upcoming days. For now, i tried using it with <Component> but got the same issue when i try to build it.

My <Directory> is wrapped inside a <StandardDirectory> which is part of <Fragment>. 

Also, if it helps, my parent tag is 

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">
</Wix>

Comment: It should not be possible to get the exact same error message if you put the `util:PermissionEx` element in the `Component` element. So, I don't know what you've done wrong at this point.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a deeper look into it :)